# Weight optimization using genetic algorithm in MATLAB

Tags: algorithm, matlab, genetic-algorithm

I am new to genetic algorithm and was hoping you guys can help me out.

I have a dataset:

```
dataset = [[3 4 4 4]
          ;[2 3 2 3]
          ;[1 1 3 2]
          ;[3 2 4 3]
          ;[0 3 1 0]];
```

where last column `[4, 3, 2, 3, 0]` represents the actual labels; and first three columns represent the feature vector `[x1 x2 x3]`.

I want to use genetic algorithm to optimize the weights `[w1 w2 w3]`.

How can I achieve this ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your weights are your optimization variables.  For the most basic optimization:

```
w = [w1 w2 w3];
x = [x1 x2 x3];
wOpt = ga(@fitnessfunc(w, x), length(w))

function y = fitnessfunc(w,x)
    y = w(1) * x(1) + w(2) * x(2) + w(3) * x(3);
```

See [MATLAB Documentation on ga](https://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/ga.html) for more options on the `ga` function call and [Passing extra parameters](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/passing-extra-parameters.html) for how to construct the program.

Remember that your WEIGHTS are the variables you're optimizing.  The `dataset` `x` values are just extra parameters.